# WSO2Emm - Authentication failed during registeration

Tags: android, wso2, wso2-iot

I create a user as entroduced in [doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Managing+Users), but in authentication phase it failed. 
I try to register using following ways, as no invitation email sent to the user!

1. using pass appear in QR code and the the username which I entered
2. change pass in carbon console for the user - try this pass with the username
3. try sending an invitation email - but no email has been sent

Error :

```
Authentication Failed: Cannot proceed the authentication. Please contact administrator.
```

PS: I working in a developer environment, I have installed server as a windows service , and android agent to my galaxy not.

Answer (score 0):

Vendor Name field of the EMM-DB's DEVICES Table is declared too short, they declared it as Varchar(11) so even if the agent code runs correctly, the server does not accept the return result from the agent. This might be the case.

You can check it from the servers console. Or you can try it with another Android Device. Also it would be beneficial to check the return String of the

```
Build.MANUFACTURER;
```

from the Android device.

Comment: dux, How can I check the return string from the device? I think it would be `samsung` as it is writen in many sites.

Comment: Hello you can write a hello world app and run the following command. Log.d("tag","Build.MANUFACTURER : "+ Build.MANUFACTURER); and check the adb logcat

Comment: The result was: `samsung`, so the length is okay as it is less than 11.

Comment: I also try to install on Samsumg S4 but I get same erroe :(

Comment: Would you please post the logcat of the device, while the error appears. There would be some error message that is like  Status: ""

Comment: As my android device is not rooted and I don't want to root it:( , I couldn't access to logcat on it, all app in play store need root access.

Comment: Logcat does not require the device to be rooted, you can access it via your computer by using adb logcat command. Please checkout the Android's documentation about it.

Comment: Can you access to https://192.168.1.52:9443/emm from your android device's browser. It seems that either the server is unreachable or the authentication (username&pass) has failed.

Comment: I can access to 192.168.1.52:9443/emm but when I try to login I get this [error] (ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/Error.jpg). also I could download app [using this link] (https://192.168.1.52:9443/emm/downloadapp).

Comment: Use admin admin to login and then create a user.

Comment: I try this but I couldn't login as a created user, also I try to login to [192.168.1.52:9443/emm](http://192.168.1.52:9443/emm) using my device with admin account but it failed and get same error as [previouse](http://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/Error.jpg)

Comment: Ok then, what is the error message on the server console, would you please post it.

Comment: here is the server [log](https://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/http_access_2015-04-20.txt)

Comment: According to the logs, IMHO there is a connection issue with the server. Which EMM version are you using? I might suggest you that, Build from the source https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Building+from+Source and please make sure that you comply with the prerequisites. After that, try again with the new version of the server.

Comment: I have downloaded binary source [version1.1.0](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/).and about prerequisites, I have:  jdk1.7.0_03 / jre 1.8.0-3, Eclipse, Android SDK and Web Browser but I hadn't install MySQL and MySQL Connector/J and git. My android device version is KitKat(4.4.2). should I install mysql  and its connector now?

Comment: I also clone [git](https://github.com/wso2/product-emm.git) but  it doesn't contain some folder like bin, /repository/resources/security and ... .

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure email in EMM settings. Otherwise it will not send an email, instead message will be popup and show you only the password and QR code (download path of the app) when you register the user.

Comment: I configure email in the emm setting [pic](https://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/emailsetting-2.png), and then add [user](https://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/adduser1-2.png) but after 8 hour no invitetion mail has been sent! also I try to register using pass appear in QR code and the the username which I entered. but as I said I get `Authentication Failed: Cannot proceed the authentication. Please contact administrator.`

Comment: I think you have entered wrong credentials. You can go to carbon console and reset the user password and try again

Comment: I change the [password](http://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~9031020/change_pass.png), but I couldn't register again. I use name and the password in carbon consol for registering!

Comment: check your network and network ports and make sure they are opened to the device. Please refer to this doc https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM110/Default+Ports+of+WSO2+Products